# gradle test fail when using compileOnly and testCompileOnly

Tags: java, servlets, intellij-idea, gradle, build.gradle

I have a small gradle library project which only have two files and two tests :

`RandomUtils.java`

```java
final class RandomUtils {

    private static final SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();

    private RandomUtils() {
    }

    static String nextRandomId() {
        return new BigInteger(130, random).toString(32);
    }

}
```

`URLUtils.java`:

```
public class URLUtils {

    private URLUtils() {
    }

    /**
     * Return the base url (eg: http://localhost:8080)
     * @param request
     * @return String
     * @throws MalformedURLException
     */
    public static String getURLBase(HttpServletRequest request) throws MalformedURLException {
        URL requestURL = new URL(request.getRequestURL().toString());
        String port = requestURL.getPort() == -1 ? "" : ":" + requestURL.getPort();
        return requestURL.getProtocol() + "://" + requestURL.getHost() + port;
    }

}
```

And these are the resepective tests :

```
@RunWith(JUnit4.class)
public class RandomUtilsTest {

    @Test
    public void testConstructorIsPrivate() throws Exception {
        Constructor constructor = RandomUtils.class.getDeclaredConstructor();
        assertTrue(Modifier.isPrivate(constructor.getModifiers()));
        constructor.setAccessible(true);
        constructor.newInstance();
    }

    @Test
    public void nextRandomId() throws MalformedURLException {
        assertNotNull(RandomUtils.nextRandomId());
    }

}
```

and

```
@RunWith(JUnit4.class)
public class URLUtilsTest {

    @Test
    public void testConstructorIsPrivate() throws Exception {
        Constructor constructor = URLUtils.class.getDeclaredConstructor();
        assertTrue(Modifier.isPrivate(constructor.getModifiers()));
        constructor.setAccessible(true);
        constructor.newInstance();
    }
    @Test
    public void getURLBase() throws MalformedURLException {
        MockHttpServletRequest request = new MockHttpServletRequest();
        request.setRequestURI("/entity");
        assertEquals("http://localhost", URLUtils.getURLBase((HttpServletRequest) request));
        request.setRequestURI(":8080/entity");
        assertEquals("http://localhost:8080", URLUtils.getURLBase((HttpServletRequest) request));
    }

}
```

I have the following `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    compileOnly("javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:${javaxServletApiVersion}")
    testCompileOnly("javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:${javaxServletApiVersion}")
    testCompileOnly("org.springframework:spring-test:${springVersion}")
    testCompileOnly("junit:junit:${junitVersion}")
}
```

I don't have any problem in intellij with the dependencies but when I try to run `./gradlew clean build` I have this error when running the tasks `:common:webutils:test` :

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/mock/web/MockHttpServletRequest
    at com.domain.api.common.webutils.URLUtilsTest.getURLBase(URLUtilsTest.java:27)
```

I have looked at the gradle [documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#sec:java_plugin_and_dependency_management) and it says that

- **compileOnly**: Compile time only dependencies, not used at runtime
- **testCompileOnly**: Additional dependencies only for compiling tests, not used at runtime

Is my configuration correct ? Why does it fail during the test if `javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:${javaxServletApiVersion}`  is present for both test and src ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You answered your own question already:

> **testCompileOnly**: Additional dependencies only for compiling tests, not used at runtime

`testCompileOnly` is just available when compiling the tests, not when executing them. If you need something only at test execution but not for compiling like `slf4j` bindings or similar, that belongs to `testRuntimeOnly`. If you need something for compiling the tests and also at runtime, then it belongs to `testImplementation`.

Comment: +1 for this helpful  answer. Otherwise, I don't use Gradle ;-) I tried by relying on the documentation but I didn't manage.  I find it really not clear. "By default, also includes the compile, runtime and test compile dependencies." seems means that it is also available during test execution.

Comment: No, you read it the other way around. There is not written that testRuntime is available where compile is available, there is written that testRuntime contains compile and thus is a super-set. I find the docs pretty clear on that. :-)

Comment: what is an example dependency that's required for test compiling but not for test runtime?

Comment: For example annotations. Or when using Groovy, some AST Transformation that does not have a runtime part but only does its work fully at compile time. ...