# Lombok integration test compile error - cannot find symbol

Tags: spring-data-jpa, lombok

I have follwing code in my `integrationTest` folder

```
import lombok.Builder;

public final class TestHelper {

        private TestHelper() {
           throw new IllegalStateException("Utility Class");
        }

        @Builder(builderMethodName = "buildDbConn")
        public static void dBConnectionBuilder(String dbUrl,String dbUser) {
             //..
    
            }
        
        public void buildTestExample(){
            buildDbConn()
                    .dbUrl("url")
                    .dbUser("usr")
                    .build();
        }
}
```

**gradle.build** I have

```
        compileOnly "org.projectlombok:lombok"
        annotationProcessor "org.projectlombok:lombok"
    
        testImplementation "org.projectlombok:lombok"
    .....

sourceSets {
    integrationTest {
        compileClasspath += main.output + test.output
        runtimeClasspath += main.output + test.output
    }
}

.....
    task integrationTest(type: Test) {
        useJUnitPlatform()
    
        description = 'Run integration tests.'
        group = 'verification'
    
        testClassesDirs = sourceSets.integrationTest.output.classesDirs
        classpath = sourceSets.integrationTest.runtimeClasspath
    
        testLogging {
            events "passed", "skipped", "failed"
        }
        mustRunAfter jacocoTestCoverageVerification
    }
```

Still I get below error when compile:

```
error: cannot find symbol
        buildDbConn()
        ^
  symbol:   method buildDbConn()
  location: class TestHelper
```

Further, same project I have dev code under `main` folder with @Builder implementation without any compilation issue.

Answer (score 2):

See [gradle setup](https://projectlombok.org/setup/gradle) from the lombok docs

```
dependencies {
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.30'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.30'
    
    testCompileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.30'
    testAnnotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.30'
}
```

Comment: I tried this too, However same result. As per this   https://stackoverflow.com/a/44507716  it is similar to`testImplementation "org.projectlombok:lombok"`

Comment: @Shabar IMHO your build file is missing the **testAnnotationProcessor** - the `annotationProcessor` declares an annotation processor only for the production sources (under the main folder). This is not the same as in the answer that you linked as that answer doesn't use annotation processors at all.

Comment: Where are you seeing the compile errors? In your IDE or from Gradle command line (or both)?

Comment: @ThomasKläger Having `org.projectlombok:lombok` in all `testCompileOnly` `testAnnotationProcessor` `testImplementation` gives the same error

Comment: @lance-java Yep, both command-line and IntelliJ same error. I tried `Invalidate Caches` as well.

Comment: @Shabar you mention that the `TestHelper` is in the integrationTest folder. Is this folder a separate source set?

Comment: @ThomasKläger, Yep, like, `src/integrationTest`, `src/main` and `src/test`. Updated some relevant parts in the `build.gradle` in the question

Comment: So, you'll likely need to add lombok to `integrationTestCompileOnly` and `integrationTestAnnotationProcessor` (assuming you've configured the integration test task to use those configurations). I'm guessing if you move the test from `src/integrationTest/java` to `src/test/java` it will compile with the configuration above

Comment: @lance-java Yay! that's the trick. Please update the answer